# Generating a List of Numbers with "Table" Causing Deviation

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to generating a list of numbers with the function table. But it caused a little deviation which I didn't expect. Let's say I need a function like:

```
Table[i,{i,0.1,1,0.2}]
```

The result I expected was {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}. It gave me a very similar output. But if I want to copy the second part of the output, I suddenly realized that the second part was not exactly 0.3. It was 0.30000000000000004`. Does anybody know what happened and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Table[i, {i, 1/10, 1, 1/5}]

Comment: Hey it really works! Why does it happen?

Comment: This is caused by the fact that many decimal numbers with a finite number of digits cannot be exactly represented by  binary numbers with a finite number of digits. For instance, 0.1 (dec) is the infinitely repeating series of 1, 1, 0, 0 in binary. Since you can't have infinite series of digits some capping needs to take place, leading to small representational errors.

Comment: From documentation: "When any number in an arithmetic expression is given with an explicit decimal point, you get an approximate numerical result for the whole expression." https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html